WARNING:root:unable to load recommended font family. Loading default PIL font, font size issues may be expected
Getting the warning -
WARNING:root:unable to load recommended font family. Loading default PIL font,font size issues may be expected.To prevent this, it is recommended to specify the value of 'font_family'.

The .tff file is in same folder. Tried Default font also got same error.
The code block the error is in
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont

font_path = 'DejaVuSans.ttf'
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, 40)

synthetic_pages = result.synthesize()
plt.imshow(synthetic_pages[0])
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

The Full code is below
from doctr.models import ocr_predictor
model = ocr_predictor(det_arch='db_resnet50', reco_arch='crnn_vgg16_bn', pretrained=True)

from doctr.io import DocumentFile
# Image
doc = DocumentFile.from_images("Test.jpg")

# Analyze
result = model(doc)

result.show()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont

font_path = 'DejaVuSans.ttf'
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, 40)

synthetic_pages = result.synthesize()
plt.imshow(synthetic_pages[0])
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()


Why are you showing 2 lots of code? Please just show the minimum code that causes the error - after having removed as much extraneous matplotlib stuff and RESnet stuff. Please add code to print os.getcwd() to ensure your program is runningfrom the directory you think it is and in which your font is located. Thank you.

@MarkSetchell One block is where the problem is and the other is full code because sometimes people need to understand what is going on in the full code before they can decipher the problem. Sometimes the problem is in the upper block even thou it is showing in this block that is why I sent the full code. Thank you

@MarkSetchell after using os.getcwd() I got the path of my folder in which the program is being stored. Thanks

And that folder contains a file called DejaVuSans.ttf ?

And if you take just lines 2,5,6 from your first example, and run them that also causes the error?

@MarkSetchell yes the folder contains the file DejaVuSans.ttf

@MarkSetchell Yes, the error is still there if I use the same venv but in new venv it worked even thou I reinstalled matplotlib in this venv multiple times. Thanks for your time.

The specific warning is in relation to a doctr function and not the matplotlib. You can use a custom font like this. Of course the font should be in the same directory or you can specify the path to the font :)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

synthetic_pages = result.synthesize(font_family ='DejaVuSans.ttf', min_font_size=40)
plt.imshow(synthetic_pages[0])
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

